# Can this sentence’s relative pronoun be omitted?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, relative-pronouns

He was shackled by the remnants of guilt (which are) indissoluble with forgiveness.

Comment: Yes, but the result is rather awkward and might be difficult to understand; partly because the clause _indissoluble with forgiveness_ is itself awkward. I presume it is meant to mean _indissoluble **even** with forgiveness_: as written it required a couple of readings for me to make any sense of it.

Comment: The meaning of the sentence is changed when **which are** is omitted.  The definite article in **the remnants** is also a factor in how we understand the sentence, either with or without **which are**.  It's also a strangely mixed metaphor, FWIW.

Comment: In terms of the full sentence, **which** is normally only used in nonrestrictive clauses in US English. So, in this case, I'd expect to see **that** instead. (But it would be perfectly fine in UK English.) More importantly, however, I'd expect to see **were** rather than **are**. It also sounds better without the article. And incorporating the other comments, we end up with: ***He was shackled by remnants of guilt that were indissoluble even with forgiveness.***

Comment: Based on that interpretation of the full sentence, I don't see the lack of the relative pronoun resulting in much of a difference—aside from making it slightly harder to understand.

Comment: You're not deleting the relative word, but the verb as well. The result is that what remains is an adjective phrase post-modifying "guilt". I don't see any real difference in meaning, though.

Comment: What is indissoluble, the guilt or only those remnants of it?  With respect to the mixed metaphor: shackled by the undissolved remnants of something ...